# Emoji and other unicode characters not appearing correctly in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unicode, emoji

I have a web app that uses messages from Twitter, for example.

A feed of JSON is used to build a list of messages, but characters such as  are displaying as question marks in a diamond. The element looks like this:

```
<div class="inner-message" ng-bind-html="unit.caption_text | linky:'_blank'"></div>
```

When I view the JSON url in Firefox and Chrome, these display fine.

Sample of head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wf-opensans-n4-active wf-active" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

One thing I've found while debugging: when the messages are all in an array of objects, but not part of $scope, I can add them to the page and the emoji show correctly.

So I think something happens in Angular to do this. I've tried changing ng-bind-html to ng-bind, but that doesn't do it. I've tried removing ng-bind-html and using {{unit.caption_text}} inside the element, but it still breaks the unicode characters.

At the moment, I need to be able to use the linky filter, to display links correctly, so ng-bind-html is necessary, but I don't believe it's the problem.

Is something happening to them in javascript to break the encoding?

Is there a way to make them display correctly?

---

### Update

This shows icons as desired, but "linky" doesn't add formatting to links.

```
<div class="inner-message">{{unit.text}}</div>
```

[image]

This shows broken characters

```
<div class="inner-message" ng-bind-html="unit.text | linky:'_blank'"></div>
```

[image]

---

### Update 2

Got there in the end, making the changes as detailed in the Pull Request, which Michael linked, to stop the characters getting messed up.

I also found it helped give consistency if I added Symbola to the font stack for these messages. You can download Symbola from [this page by George Douros](http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/) . I ran it through a .ttf to .woff converter to get slightly better browser support, offering two alternatives.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/madhur/angular-emoji-popup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Note: This post does not display as intended on Chrome, as it doesn't support Emoji characters

It looks like Angular's `$sanitize` service attempts to convert the characters to their HTML-entity equivalent. However, for certain single emoji characters, it splits it to 2. As can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/fDDen3bnnrQUvx3JfKgw?p=preview,

```
$scope.sanitizedText = $sanitize('');
```

output in the template as

```
{{sanitizedText}}
```

shows `&#55357;&#56904;`. Why? I don't know.

This means that anything using `$sanitize` will effectively break such characters. This includes

- Output shown using `ng-bind-html` that *hasn't* gone through `$sce.trustAsHtml`
- Anything passed through `linky`, as can be seen in the [linky source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/filter/linky.js), it calls `$sanitize`.

So, you *can* avoid HTML going through `$sanitize` as long as

- You pass the string through [$sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#trustAsHtml)
- You don't pass it through the Angular provided linky filter, but roll your own that doesn't `$sanitize` the input.

An example filter is below:

```
app.filter('unsafeLinky', function($sce) {
  // Regex from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/filter/linky.js#L5
  var urlRegex = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/|(mailto:)?[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@)\S*[^\s.;,(){}<>])/gi;
  return function(input, target) {
    var targetHTML = target ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '';
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input.replace(urlRegex,'<a href="$1"' + targetHTML + '>$1</a>'));
  }
});
```

Which can be used as

```
<p ng-bind-html="text | unsafeLinky:'_blank'"></p>
```

You can see a demo of this at http://plnkr.co/edit/sRJmt4YVO8udJInCd4Cy?p=preview

As suggested by the name, this unsafeLinky filter is unsafe. Be sure to trust where the original text comes from.

As suggested at the start of this answer, [Chrome doesn't display Emoji characters properly](http://blog.getemoji.com/post/73341182572/its-2014-why-doesnt-chrome-support-emoji). To get the characters showing in Chrome, you might have to use some sort of image-replacement. In any case, I suspect that is beyond the scope of this particular question.

**Update**

There is PR for Angular that might fix this, making the above work-around unnecessary once it's merged in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6911

Comment: Apparently `$sanitize` is broken. Those references decode to codepoints reserved for the "surrogate pair" mechanism of UTF-16; someone's iterating over UTF-16 code units instead of actual codepoints, thereby breaking *everything* outside of the BMP.  Way to go library author.

Comment: Alex, I found that last night and it works. Your answer is correct! I also downloaded a font face to give consistent handling of the emojis, and added that too. Will reference it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the regex above was breaking on some urls such as bit.yl shortlinks so i adapted another example i found somewhere:

```
twitterApp.filter('parseUrl', function($sce) {
    var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;
    return function(text) {        
        angular.forEach(text.match(urlPattern), function(url) {
            text = text.replace(url, "<a target=\"_blank\" href="+ url + ">" + url +"</a>");
        });
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);        
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<p ng-bind-html="tweet.text | parseUrl"></p>
```