# Convert UTF 8 characters in facebook page json feed

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, utf-8

How to convert the special characters here:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285
```

Using javascript?

The characters are like:

```
\u0993\u09df\u09c7\u09ac \u09a1\u09c7\u09ad\u09c7\u09b2\u09aa\u09ae\u09c7\u09a8\u09cd\u099f
```

Comment: Just use any JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally javascript consider all string as a Unicode encoded , So you can use the same response without coverting .

Comment: Well, Im using it with AngularJS, and the output is all encoded.

Comment: @SidFerreira Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994026/emoji-and-other-unicode-characters-not-appearing-correctly-in-angular